# Image at wrong location on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to make a game that is based on cursor movement(like agar.io) but when the image is rendered on the canvas it is put about 4 times farther away from the origin than I want it to be.

Javascript, CSS, HTML:

```js
function combined() {
    movechar(direction())
    draw()
}
function draw() {
    //context.save()
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //cont.restore()
    context.drawImage(img, xChar, yChar)
    //context.drawImage(img,1,1)
}
function direction() {
    var delX = xCor - xChar
    var delY = yCor - yChar
    var delta = Math.sqrt(delX * delX + delY * delY)
    var dirX = delX / delta
    var dirY = delY / delta
    return [dirX, dirY]
}
function movechar(dirArr) {
    xChar += dirArr[0]
    yChar += dirArr[1]
}
var d = new Date()
var sTime = d.getTime()
console.log(sTime)
var canvas = document.getElementById("playerCanvas")
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.im
var img = new Image()
img.src = "char.bmp", img.width = 8, img.height = 8
var xCor = 0
var yCor = 0
var xChar = canvas.clientWidth / 2
var yChar = canvas.clientHeight / 2
$("canvas").on("mousemove", function (e) { xCor = e.clientX; yCor = e.clientY; })
function docload() { setInterval(combined,30) }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
canvas#playerCanvas {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    margin : 0%;
    background-image : url("floor2.bmp");
    background-repeat : repeat;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>wizard.io</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="koolLooks.css">
    <noscript>Ur browser sux</noscript>
</head>
<body onload="docload()">
    <canvas id="playerCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="ok2hax.js"></script>
    <script src="eligal2hax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### When canvas resolution does not match the display size.

When you render to the canvas it is usually in canvas pixels. The number of pixels in the canvas is set via the `width` and `height` properties and defines the canvas resolution.

When the canvas is displayed and you set the display size via the `canvas.style` with and height this does not change the canvas resolution, just the size. The result is that you stretch the canvas pixels to cover many CSS pixels. Then when you try to draw at a mouse coord which is in CSS pixels it does not match the pixel on the canvas under the mouse.

To make sure you do get a mismatch it is best to avoid using the `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height` properties at all and just set the `canvas.width` and `height` properties directly. NOTE these values are always pixels and are not postfixed ie `canvas.width = "100%"` will not work

#### The problem is simple to fix.

Below I have made changes to your snippet and marked them with comments

```js
function combined() {
    movechar(direction())
    draw()
}
function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // as your images had bad URL I put boxes in there place
    
    context.strokeRect(xChar, yChar,50,50)
     context.fillRect(xCor-10, yCor-10,20,20)
}
function direction() {
    var delX = xCor - xChar
    var delY = yCor - yChar
    var delta = Math.sqrt(delX * delX + delY * delY)
    var dirX = delX / delta
    var dirY = delY / delta
    return [dirX, dirY]
}
function movechar(dirArr) {
    xChar += dirArr[0]
    yChar += dirArr[1]
}
var d = new Date()
var sTime = d.getTime()

var canvas = document.getElementById("playerCanvas")
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')

//====================================================================
// IMPORTANT BIT
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// set the canvas size to the window size

canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

context.im
var xCor = 0
var yCor = 0

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// use the canvas height and width rather than clientWidth height

var xChar = canvas.width / 2
var yChar = canvas.height / 2
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

// change listener just to make it work no JQuery
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) { xCor = e.clientX; yCor = e.clientY; })
function docload() { setInterval(combined,30) }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
canvas#playerCanvas {

    /* not needed as they are stretching the canvas
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;

    */

    margin : 0%;
    background-image : url("floor2.bmp");
    background-repeat : repeat;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>wizard.io</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="koolLooks.css">
    <noscript>Ur browser sux</noscript>
</head>
<body onload="docload()">
    <canvas id="playerCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="ok2hax.js"></script>
    <script src="eligal2hax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you get the `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` variables? Otherwise, thank you.

Comment: @opfromthestart `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` are standard globals as part of the window object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window